# Is there a public wiki or group discussing the backstory and or codes?

Tags: ingress

Whenever I come across some Ingress related site, it tends to be a one off blog entry, a shared doc that's on one topic, or a wiki that's totally un-fleshed out and apparently dead [I'm talking about [ingresswiki.org](http://ingresswiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) here].

Is there a better site or wiki that is cataloging the backstory, the media, the way to decode each passcode from the media, and or strategies and end-game theories?

Outside of asking, and hearing about closed forums and such I haven't found anything that seems more comprehensive than having 2 people working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've pretty much [dismissed the code portion of the game as worthless](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/ingress-discuss/discuss-game-play/Br4cdsGf5tU) since even if you spend time on it and figure one out, they're likely going to be already redeemed and worthless by the time you do - unless you're really fast and dedicated.

You probably already know about the [official niantic site](http://www.nianticproject.com/), but that's the best catalog of the backstory even if there doesn't seem to be linked discussion from there.

As already mentioned, the [Ingress Field Guide](http://ingressfieldguide.com/) is the best unofficial source of somewhat organized game info I've seen so far.  Their info on gameplay is also the most useful for new players I've seen.

To add a few more sources not yet mentioned

- [Google Groups Ingress Communities](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2852767?hl=en&ref_topic=2799231) - Linked to from Google's support pages for the game
- [Ingress Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/) - You probably either like Reddit's format or you don't, but it's certainly active
- The [Google + Ingress page](https://plus.google.com/s/ingress) - Mostly just people doing fanboy stuff to try to get invites, but maybe that will change once the game opens up to a wider audience

Comment: Thank you. I'm amused at your description of the G+ Ingress page. I'm thinking of un-following it just because it's basically become an "invite please" stream. I am hoping it'll change. Reddit will always be the best place to find teen self-pics plundered from badly shared phones etc. Which is why I've been avoiding it and not been considering it for serious purposes.

Answer (score 1):

- You have the [Ingress Field Guide](http://ingressfieldguide.com/) where you can find passcodes, and some explanations of how you can discover some.
- Google + is full of discussion about passcode (search [passcode ingress](https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/ingress%20passcode))
- an unofficial [Niantic Project Wiki](http://niantic.schlarp.com/start) filled up with passcode investigations results

Comment: Thanks; I do find the field guide to be closer along the lines of what I was hoping for. Basically Ingress was professed to be sort of JJ Abrams inspired, and yet I don't see something fan-wise that's along the lines of FringePedia.net. Though the field guide and project wiki are pretty close. http://www.engadget.com/2012/11/15/google-launches-ingress/